# jQuery cycle IE6/7 links not working?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-cycle

I am having some issues with jQuery Cycle and IE6/7. It seems that IE6/7 are adding a behaviour:none style which is the only difference between the 2 sites.

I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue too, and if you were able to fix it at all.

Answer (score 0):

As with weird most IE6/7 issues, try adding:

```
* {zoom:1}
```

to your CSS. If that fixes it, you know you are having a good ol' hasLayout issue.